# Формат ГОСТ 34.10.2012 для js\php

Tags: javascript, php, криптография, криптопро

Всем привет.
Нужна библиотека или же какой то пример как создать хеш по ГОСТ Р 34.10.2012 для js ну или на крайней случай для php.
я находил варианты с алгоритмом для openssl но они не подходят. Так же сейчас используем для генерации подписи пакет  [vgoma/crypto-pro](https://github.com/vgoma/crypto-pro) но там  другой ГОСТ (34.11.2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто то столкнется с такой же проблемой то есть [библиотека](https://github.com/Aleksandr-ru/RusCryptoJS) которая и возвращает ГОСТ 2012 (34.10.2012). И вот ее [демо](https://aleksandr-ru.github.io/RusCryptoJS/rutoken.html)

Все работает на ура с Vue3